# How to add icon beside the lable using Vue Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js

I have this vue bootstrap input field:

```
<b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name">
<validation-provider
    #default="{ errors }"
    name="Mapping Name"
    rules="required"
>
    <b-form-input
        v-model="mappingData.mapping_name"
        :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
        id="mappingName"
        placeholder="Enter a maping name"
    />
    <small class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</small>
</validation-provider>
</b-form-group>
```

The output is look like this :

[image]

Now, beside ( Right side of the name ) the **Name** label I want to add a icon which is:

```
<feather-icon
    icon="AlertCircleIcon"
    class="mr-50 my-icon"
    v-b-tooltip.hover.top="'Some tooltip text'"
/>
```

So for that I have added this after the : `<b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name">`. Now it look like this:

[image]

But its should be beside the **name** label.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the [template slot](//v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) label of [b-form-group](//bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-group#label) like this:

```
<b-form-group label-for="name">
              <validation-provider
                #default="{ errors }"
                name="Mapping Name"
                rules="required"
              >
                <template slot="label">
                  Name
                  <feather-icon
                    v-b-tooltip.hover.top="'Some tooltip text'"
                    icon="AlertCircleIcon"
                    class="mr-50 my-icon"
                  />
                </template>
                <b-form-input
                  v-model="mappingData.mapping_name"
                  :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
                  id="mappingName"
                  placeholder="Enter a maping name"
                />
                <small class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</small>
              </validation-provider>
            </b-form-group>
```